# Do these code snippets do the same thing in React

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks

my course is telling me this is the solution to checking if contacts already has {name} in it.

```
useEffect(() => {
    const nameIsDuplicate = () => {
      const found = contacts.find((contact) => contact.name === name);
      if (found !== undefined) {
        return true;
      }
      return false;
    };

    if (nameIsDuplicate()) {
      setDuplicate(true);
    } else {
      setDuplicate(false);
    }
  }, [name, contacts, duplicate]);
```

Does my code do the same thing?

```
 useEffect(() => {
    if (contacts.includes(name)) {
      setDuplicate(true)
    } else {
      setDuplicate(false)
    }
  }, [name, contacts, duplicate]);
```

Comment: What happens when you *test it*?

Answer (score 0):

No, contact seems to be a list, like:

```
[
   {name: "Mario"},
   {name: "Andrea"},
   ...
]
```

I guess this given the predicate for the `find` method:

```
contact.name === name
```

In the second example it is using the `includes` passing the same `name` variable that seems to indicate a string, so in the second snippet `contacts.includes` will be always false

Comment: edited, but the result is the same: https://linuxhint.com/javascript-array-contains-includes